# Laravel 4 Eloquent, "dynamic" relations?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Basically the scenario is as follows. A section is a resource blueprint that can contain multiple fields, an Entry is a record of this blueprint.

```
class Entry extends Model
{
    public function section()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Section');
    }
}
```

My problem so far: 
So let's assume I have a `Field` model, where the field can have different types, and one value (its content).

Ideally the dynamic content property would be a one to one relation like

```
class Field extends Model
{

    public function content()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('ContentModel');
    }
}
```

However, the `ContentModel` class would be based on the type value of the field.

Each type represents a different typemodel, that knows how to write its value (for the sake of simplicity, let's assume there are 3 types, `input`, `text`, `int`, and corresponding 3 model classes `ContentInput`, `ContentText`, and `ContentInt`)

```
sections (Section)
- id (char, 36) // uuid
- label (varchar)
- handle (varchar)


entries (Section)
- id (char, 36) // uuid
- section_id (char, 36) // uuid of the section


fields (Field)
- id (integer)
- section_id (char, 36) // uuid of the section
- type (varchar) // the content model class
- handle (varchar)
- label (varchar)


content_input (ContentInput)
- id
- entry_id (char, 36) // entry record of a section 
- field_id (integer)
- value (varchar)


content_text (ContentText)
- id
- entry_id (char, 36) // entry record of a section
- field_id (integer)
- value (text)


content_int (ContentInt)
- id
- entry_id (char, 36) // entry record of a section
- field_id (integer)
- value (integer)

// ... there're many more content types.
```

I was thinking of polymorphic relations, but they won't fit in this specific case.

Is there any efficient way to achieve this with eloquent?

**[EDIT NOTES]**:

I've updated the examples above as I was a bit unclear.
One possible solution would be to dynamically create the entry model class based on the section definition.

```
class Entry_249fcb61_4253_47d5_80ab_e012e19e7727 extends Entry
{
    protected $with = ['gettext', 'getinput', 'getint'];  

    public function gettext()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ContentText', 'entry_id');
    }

    // and so on
}
```

Still don't know if that's the way to go.

Comment: Not a solution but something slightly similar: A few months ago I was playing around with a "[scaffold package](https://github.com/nils-werner/laravel-scaffold/blob/master/src/NilsWerner/Scaffold/Managers/FieldManager.php)" that did some sort of dynamic table layout probing to find out what column types where there. It would then create instances of the specific field types.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way but here is the solution I came up with for a similar problem I had

```
fields (Field)
- id
- inputId -> nullable -> default = null
- textId -> nullable -> default = null
- intId -> nullable -> default = null
```

Field.php

```
public function input()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Content_input', 'id', 'inputId');
    }

public function text()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Content_text', 'id', 'textId');
    }

public function integer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Content_int', 'id', 'intId');
    }
```

you can load these relationships when you are retrieving Field and then you can check which content type each has by checking which of the 3 fields is not null

Comment: Yes, that would work, and in fact, it's pretty close to a solution I came up earlier (which involved dynamic creation of models etc.). However, content types should be added dynamically, so the field class can't know about the content type classes. I'll update the example above to get a more precise picture of the whole thing.